# Multiple True Items in a Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I want multiple true items to pull from data in my query. I can only get it to pull for 1.

I've tried adding, 'true value' after the current true value but errors

```
=QUERY('Stats Report Data'!A3:BT395, "select H,C,D,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AX,AY,AZ,BA,BB,BC,BD,AV,AJ,AL,AM,AN,AO,AP,AQ,AR,AS,AT,BF where C = 'true value'")
```

This pulls one value from the data, but I want to pull 2+. When adding another true value after this one, I get a `VALUE error`.

Answer (score 0):

in `QUERY` you can expand criteria with operators `OR` and `AND`:

**https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where**

```
=QUERY('Stats Report Data'!A3:BT395, 
 "select H,C,D,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AX,AY,AZ,BA,BB,BC,BD,AV,AJ,AL,AM,AN,AO,AP,AQ,AR,AS,AT,BF 
  where C = 'true value' 
    and C = 'true value2'", 0)
```